# Changing animation from view to view

Tags: ios

I have a tabbar application with 4 tabs and a navigation bar hooked to one. On the tab with the navigation bar I have a button that brings you to a new page. I also have one that brings you back to the tab page, but I have a problem. When going back to the tab page the animation is going the wring way. I did this all with storyboards so no coding. I looked around and want to put this in the code:

```
- (void) pushController: (UIViewController*) controller
     withTransition: (UIViewAnimationTransition) transition
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];        
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But i have no idea how and where to put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [Apple guide to creating a custom segue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html). Your perform code would look something like this:

```
- (void)perform {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [self.sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];        
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Then in your storyboard, set the type of the segue to Custom, and then enter the name of your custom segue class.